# Scale delayed Job workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, delayed-job

I have been using delayed_job_mongoid in my rails 4.2.7 application.I am trying for a solution to run or add more  workers on a production severs depending on queue size.I like to increase the number of workers if there is a spike in queue messages.I have seen solutions like workless which is specifically designed for heroku.Is there any solution that works for any servers

Is there any working solutions

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean with _autoscale workers_? Start more servers? Start more threads? Start more workers? How many? Why don't you configure run more worker all the time?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" including the linked pages. You're asking us to recommend solutions, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Since [Delayed::Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) stores all your jobs in the database, I'd just monitor the existing number in the MongoDB collection queue. You'll then have a baseline of what a normal number of jobs should be and when the queue reaches some percentage greater/less than what is normal, you can launch/stop new workers.

In order to stop selected workers you'll need to grab the pids from the `/tmp/pids` directory to know which ones to stop when you're done with them.